# Amazon blocked Python 3 scraping using bs4, requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code works fine a few days ago when I run it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import requests

def getWeekMostRead(date):
    nonfiction_page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/charts/"+date.isoformat()+"/mostread/nonfiction")
    content = "amazon"+date.isoformat()+"_nonfiction.html"
    with open(content, "w", encoding="utf-8") as nf_file:
        print(nonfiction_page.content, file=nf_file)

    mostRead_nonfiction = BeautifulSoup(nonfiction_page.content, features="html.parser")

    nonfiction = mostRead_nonfiction.find_all("div", class_="kc-horizontal-rank-card")

    mostread = []
    for books in nonfiction:
        if books.find(class_="kc-rank-card-publisher") is None:
            mostread.append((
                books.find(class_="kc-rank-card-title").string.strip(),
                books.find(class_="kc-rank-card-author").string.strip(),
                "",
                books.find(class_="numeric-star-data").small.string.strip()
            ))
        else:
            mostread.append((
                books.find(class_="kc-rank-card-title").string.strip(),
                books.find(class_="kc-rank-card-author").string.strip(),
                books.find(class_="kc-rank-card-publisher").string.strip(),
                books.find(class_="numeric-star-data").small.string.strip()
            ))
    return mostread

mostread = []
date = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
while date >= datetime.date(2015,1,1):
    print("Scraped data from "+date.isoformat())
    mostread.extend(getWeekMostRead(date))
    date -= datetime.timedelta(7)
print("Currently saving scraped data to AmazonCharts.csv")
with open("AmazonCharts.csv", "w") as csv:
    counter = 0
    print("ID,Title,Author,Publisher,Rating", file=csv)
    for book in mostread:
        counter += 1
        print('AmazonCharts'+str(counter)+',"'+book[0]+'","'+book[1]+'","'+book[2]+'","'+book[3]+'"', file=csv)
    csv.close()
```

For some reason, today I tried to run it again and I got this included in the returned HTML file:

```
To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.\r\n\r\nFor information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac for advertising use cases.
```

I understand that Amazon is a heavy anti-scraping data (or at least I read so from some replies and threads). I tried to use headers and delays in the code but it does not work. Would there be another way to try this? Or if I should wait, how long should I wait?

Comment: They have probably logged your IP address as trying to scrape their website, so it's unlikely that a delay is going to allow you to access it again. Have you considered using their APIs as they suggest?

Comment: I did try to scrape the fiction instead and it works - now I am figuring out how to do it for the non-fiction. The problem is that I am doing this for a school project, so I probably should not use API. :(

Comment: I got this error for a 404 response. But a valid URL works good. Probably you are black listed.  Consider using a User-Agent header also.

Comment: If you're doing this for a school project, you *should* consider using an API, since scraping is against the usage policies of Amazon and can get not just you, but everyone in your school blocked from accessing their services.

Comment: Just a question. Can I go through each HTML, save them locally, and then use bs4 to scrape the data based on those saved HTML's?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

After a while, I have figured the solution. It is rather simply - there was no "2020-01-01" on Amazon, instead, I fixed it "2020-01-05".

Answer (score 5):

As you noted, Amazon is very anti-scraping. There's an entire industry built around scraping data from Amazon, and Amazon has its own API access to sell, so it's in their best interest to stop people from freely grabbing data from their pages.

Based on your code, I suspect you made too many requests too quickly and were IP banned. When scraping sites, it's usually best to scrape responsibly by not going too fast, rotating user agents, and rotating IPs through a proxy service.

To seem less programmatic, you can also try randomizing request timing to seem more human.

Even with all of that, you'll still likely hit issues with this. Amazon is not an easy site to reliably scrape.

Answer (score 2):

You can try add *User-Agent* in headers in the requests use this one

```py
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    'From': 'personal@domain.com'  # This is another valid field
}

url = "YOURLINK"
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Should be ok.